# How paradoxical that the world’s greatest chefs

Tags: parsing

> How paradoxical that the world’s greatest chefs have all been men!
>   Cooking would clearly seem to be a field that lies exclusively within
>   women’s realm, yet the annals of cookery are replete with masculine
>   names: Brillat Savarin, Ritz, Diat, Larousse.

I have two questions for you:

1)Why did the author use "that" after the adjective "paradoxical"? we have the examples "how big is the house" or "how good you are at learning languages" without having "that".

2) What is the difference between "Cooking would clearly seem to be" and "Cooking clearly seem to be"?

Source: 1100 words you need to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask

> Why did the author use "that" after the adjective "paradoxical"?

**How paradoxical** is an exclamation.

Exclamations often have no explicit verb. The verb is implicit:

{something}  **IS** so very paradoxical.

What is the "something"?

In your sentence, the *that*-clause is the "something"; the *that*-clause is the subject of the verb IS which is implicit in the exclamation:

That the world's great chefs have all been men
IS
(so very) paradoxical.

We could also make that sentence using **it** as a kind of placeholder for the content supplied by the *that*-clause:

> How paradoxical it is, that the world's great chefs have all been men.

P.S. Compare the following where the *that*-clause is the subject:

> That the Ferrari is a fast car is undisputed.
>
> That a triangle has three sides is a basic fact of geometry.
>
> That the starving sailors had resorted to cannibalism was not released
>   to the public.
>
> How gruesome, that the starving sailors had resorted to cannibalism
>
> How interesting, that this fact had not been released to the public.

Answer (score 10):

1. A paradox is a situation, so the adverb "paradoxically" does not describe a person or a thing. In both of the examples you cite, the adjectives refer to the object or person.

Look at another adjective as an example - let's use the word *brilliant*:

> How brilliant the world's greatest chefs are!

Here "brilliant" is describing the chefs themselves. They are brilliant.

> How brilliant that the world's greatest chefs are men!

Here the word "brilliant" is not describing the chefs, but the *situation* in which all the world's greatest chefs are men. *That* is needed to introduce the clause that follows to show that it is the *situation* that is paradoxical, not the chefs.

---

2. The word "would" is sometimes used to make a sentence *less direct.*

For example:

> I expect you to be home at 4pm.
>
> I would expect you to be home at 4pm.

The first is very specific - the person expects you home at 4pm. It could even be taken as a demand that you must be home at that time. The second sentence, however, is looser; it implies that this is the time they would expect, perhaps under usual circumstances or thereabouts.

Likewise, in your sentence, the writer is trying to establish that a paradox exists. They are suggesting that cooking is *normally* something associated with women, and yet most of the greatest chefs are men. It would seem odd to first make a bold statement that the world's greatest chefs are men, and then make an equally bold but contrary statement that cooking is "exclusively within women's realm". I believe the writer has used the word "would" to soften the statement, and imply that this is what you would normally expect rather than what is definitely the case.

Comment: Let's also hope extract was at least written before the 70's too. These days, it's a tad 'itchy' ;) *Edit* I looked it up...  1971... borderline :/

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, quite. Thankfully we are just here to comment on the English.

Comment: Thanks @Astralbee. The explanation was really informative and great. In the first line you said "the adjective paradoxically". I think "paradoxically" is an adverb.

Comment: @Astralbee as you said " That is needed to introduce the clause that follows." But in the sentence "How brilliant the world's greatest chefs are!" we have a clause after "How brilliant" too.

Comment: @EnglishLearner You are quite right, and corrected. "Paradoxical" is an adjective, as are "big" and "good" in your two examples.

Comment: @EnglishLearner Okay I have edited to clarify that point too. It isn't specifically that a clause follows that demands the word "that" to be in there, but it correctly introduces it because the *situation* involving the chefs is paradoxical, not the chefs themselves.

Comment: Agree with 1, not so much with 2. In your example 'suggest' is the word making the sentence less direct.  Consider:  "I suggest you stop that" vs the order for comparison.  In OP's example 'would' poses the question/supposition, whereas OP's alternative (with the correction 'seem' -> 'seems') makes it definite - which is obviously not the case given all the books.

Comment: @mcalex I accept that "suggest" is not a strong word to begin with. How about "ask"? You wouldn't say "I ask you to stop that", you would just, well, ask. Saying "would" anything implies that  you haven't actually got to that stage yet, but you will. There are lots of other examples... "I would expect" is less certain that "I expect". Do you agree or should I change my example?

Comment: I do think that it's the question (vs definiteness) created by *would* rather than it being less direct. There's an inferred intro like 'Based on the conception that almost all cooking is done by women, it would clearly seem ... '*  On the other hand, OP's alternative of "Cooking clearly seems to be ... (the exclusive realm of women)" is a statement of fact.  It's not a true statement of fact as a lot of cooking books are written by men as detailed.  I think you're more accurate in your comment: the added 'would' makes it less certain but in the sense of being definite, over being direct.

Comment: In this case, "would" is also used to introduce doubt. "Cooking clearly seems to be" is a straight-froward fact statement. On the other hand, "Cooking clearly would seem to be" has a tone of sarcasm. The author is saying that you would think so, but implying that you would be wrong in thinking so.